# How to use tryMax in Gatling for a blank attribute, logout and restart the iteration?

Tags: gatling

I know I can use tryMax to restart a scenario and use .exists() to validate if an attribute exists. How do I incorporate the two together?

Answer (score 4):

If you have checks in an exec inside the tryMax and that check fails, it will try it again from the beginning of the tryMax block.

EX:

```
val TestScenarioThatRestartsOnFail: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("ScenarioNameHere")
.tryMax(2) {
  exec(
    http("zzzz")
      .get("zzz")
      .check(xxxx)
  )
  .exec(
    http("zzzz")
      .get("zzz")
      .check(xxxx)
  )
}
```

So basically any check that fails in the entire tryMax{} block, will make the entire block run again.

You can also chain multiple tryMax blocks if you need to retry different number of times different requests

```
val TestScenarioThatRestartsOnFail: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("ScenarioNameHere")
.tryMax(2) {
  exec (
    http ("zzzz")
    .get ("zzz")
    .check (xxxx)
  )
}.tryMax(2) {
  exec(
    http("zzzz")
    .get("zzz")
    .check(xxxx) 
  )
}
```

If you encounter checks that are **"optional"** hence they might sometimes fail, but you don't want to trigger the tryMax for those checks, use the `optional` method like :

`.check(regex("/admin-ng/login.[^\"]*.css").find.optional.saveAs("login_css"))`

This will not fail the check if it is not fulfilled, in this example, the element we search for is not in the response.